# How do I see the logs for Fabric Composer

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I would like to view the runtime and client logs generated by Fabric Composer but cannot find them. Can you please provide guidance on how to access the logs?.

Answer (score 3):

## Runtime Logs

If you run `docker ps -a` you should see 3 running docker containers. One of the docker containers will be the chaincode container (where the Composer runtime is executing your logic).

It has a generated name something like: `dev-vp0-4968dea9e3a69670235d9283859801ab5df6f18398f15711d6f5426123955f9f`

Look for its container id, and then run `docker logs <container id>`
You can follow the logs using `docker logs -f`

If you are on the Mac you can also view the logs using the Kitematic GUI.
Fabric Composer log entries are tagged with `[Concerto]` (the old codename)

## Client Logs

The client-side APIs (written in Node) can also generate logs. Set the DEBUG environment variable to enable debugging. E.g (for Linux and Mac):

`export DEBUG=composer:*`

INFO and higher log messages will be sent to `stdout` by default. All logs will also be logged to disk under a `./logs` folder.

Please see the docs here:
https://fabric-composer.github.io/problems/diagnostics.html