# (hyperledger composer playground) Can you see results of console.log('something') in browser?

Tags: javascript, browser, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Where `console.log('')` gets printed, if I don't have a local setup and working on code inside the browser.

Comment: i guess it should print in console of developer tools in browser

Answer (score 2):

you can see the output in the Developer console. In Firefox and Chrome browsers for example - hit CTRL-SHIFT-I and it pops up - then go to ...Console..JS and you can see what you `console.log()` there

Beyond that (eg. client and runtime logs) see  [How do I see the logs for Fabric Composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42695751/how-do-i-see-the-logs-for-fabric-composer)

Comment: It works fine for online playground. But does not work when I run the local playground. Do I need to do something to get it working in local playground ?

Answer (score 1):

Writing `console.log` in a Transaction can be used to debug and see the incoming and outgoing data. It can be viewed using developer options by pressing `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`i` in Chrome or Firefox.

But if you are using Composer Playground **locally**, then the log output is written to the Docker Container.